# Pilling two obj with OnMousePressed on top of each other in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Been trying around and searching but couldn't find any solution, so I finally decided to give up and ask further...

Creating a javafx app, I load tiles in a TilePane.

This tiles are clickable and lead to a details page  of their respective content.

On each tile, if they do belong to a certain pack, I do display the pack name, that is also clickable and lead to a page showing that specific pack content.

So that means the container, the tile, that is a Pane is clickable and on top of it I have a Label that is claickable also. What happens is when I do click the Label, it also triggers the Pane onMousePressed()... Here is a part of the tile creation code, the part focused  on the onMousePressed(). I tried to make the Pane react by double click and the Label by single, it works, but I want to Pane to open with a single click.

I would be more than thankfull for any ideas how to solve that.

```
public DownloadTile (Downloadable upload, MainApp mainApp) {
    _mainApp = mainApp;
    _upload = upload;
    _tile = new Pane();
    _tile.setPrefHeight(100);
    _tile.setPrefWidth(296);
    _tile.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff;");
    _tile.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
}

public void refresh() {
    _tile.getChildren().clear();
    _tile.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown() /*&& event.getClickCount() == 2*/) {
                _mainApp.showDownloadDialog(dt, _upload);
            }
        }
    });

    if (_upload.getPack() != null) {
        Label pack = new Label();
        pack.setText(_upload.getPack());
        pack.getStyleClass().add("pack-link");
        pack.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        pack.relocate(10, 48);

        _tile.getChildren().add(pack);

        pack.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    _mainApp.showPackPage(_upload);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your label will receive the mouseclick first (since it's on top), so after you have processed the click, you can stop it from being passed down the chain using 'consume':

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(
        (Event event) -> {    

    // process your click here

    System.out.println("Panel clicked");
    pane.requestFocus();
    event.consume();
};
```

Comment: That is exactly what I spent hours searching for, but obviously couldnt speak my mind correctly for searching and did not see it in the docs... Thank you so much! event.consume()